# URL Rewrite not changing URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use friendly urls on my site.

Basically, I want www.example.com/index.php?view=contact to display as www.example.com/view/contact - with contact changing to the various other pages.

Here is what I have cobbled together for the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^view/([^/\.]+)/?$ /view=$1 [L]
```

Although, it does not work. Any suggestions?

Mod_rewrite is on and I can get to change it to www.example.com/contact/.

Comment: How does apache work on `www.example.com/view=contact`?

Comment: mode_rewrite on apache config

Comment: You want `www.example.com/view=contact` OR `www.example.com/?view=contact`?